# How can I use multi-threading to allow multiple clients on to a server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I have two java classes, one for a server and one for a client. The connection is established between both of them using a regular socket. How can I allow many instances of the client class to connect to the server simultaneously using multi-threading?
I tried searching on SO but I couldn't really find any concise/clear answers.

Here are my important methods (both of them are in the Server class):

```
public void startRunning() {

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(portNum, 10); // port num and backlog

        while (true) {
            try {

                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();  //sets up streams
                whileChatting(); //exchanges messages
            } catch (EOFException e1) {
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection");

            } finally {
                closeEverything();  //closes all streams
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {

    showMessage(" Waiting for connections...\n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Connected to "
            + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

}
```

Comment: A "traditional" approach is it spawn a new thread on the server for each client;  use a [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). Depending on your application, you might be able to use a [Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) to reduce the number of threads needed.  There are lots of examples available on the web.  However your question is too broad for this site's format.  Please ask a specific question about some code you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example. A new Thread replies to every new incoming Client.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server implements Runnable {
  public static final int port = 5678;


  public void run() {
    try{
       ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

       while (true) 
       {
           final Socket client = server.accept();
           new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                      try{
                          ObjectInputStream in = 
                          new ObjectInputStream( client.getInputStream() );
                         String msg = (String) in.readObject();
                         System.out.println(msg);
                        }
                      catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e);}

          }}.start();
       }
      }
    catch(IOException e){System.err.println(e);}
    }

}

class Client {

  public void writeMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
     new ObjectOutputStream((new Socket("localhost",Server.port).getOutputStream())).writeObject(msg);
  }
}

public class ClientServer{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Server server = new Server("My Multithreaded Server");
    new Thread(server).start();
    Client client1 = new Client();
    Client client2 = new Client();
    client1.writeMessage("Hello !");
    client2.writeMessage("Give me five !");
  }
}
```

Comment: My server class is already extending JFrame, would you mind editing this so that it implements the Runnable interface?

Comment: it's done. not a big change as you can see

Comment: What is that super call in the constructor?

Comment: I have to remove it now that Server doesn't extend Thread any more ...

Comment: I understand your code but I just dont know how to apply it to mine. I've edited my question to include the most important methods. Any help appreciated!

Comment: as far as i understand i think you have to create the new Thread as I did in the Server class to execute your setupStreams() and  whileChatting() in the run() method of the Thread

Comment: Does your code have anything to guarantee that all clients will be able to see each others' messages?

Comment: the server has to deal with that (ie broadcast one client message to other clients so it must have a list of all connected clients). My server doesn't do that. It was not the question you asked